# Objective-C MapKit Overlay on entire map

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mapkit

How would I create an overlay that colors the entire map a certain color? Then I need to be able to place annotations on top of it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Does this overlay need to cover the entire globe or just a certain extent?

Comment: It needs to be the entire globe.

Comment: You could use MapBox and design a custom map with whatever colorscheme you want.  I've used it and the transition from MKMaps was pretty easy.

Comment: This question is answered with a much simpler and robust solution elsewhere (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227884/how-to-dark-the-mkmapview-s-background-color-and-do-not-dark-the-mkoverlays-in)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is [MKOverlay](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [MKOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html). 
You can find apple's code in one of the apps mentioned in 'Related sample code'. in above protocol and class reference page.

*EDIT : As Per the comments previous code was not working as-is. Heres a [MKMapDimOverlay  GitHub](https://github.com/lukya/MKMapDimOverlay) project which you can simply integrate using CocoaPods. I have also made the relevant changes in following code in the answer.*

To explain briefly, following is code for adding a dark overlay on entire map.

You need to **create an overlay and add it to the map view.**

```
MKMapDimOverlay *dimOverlay = [[MKMapDimOverlay alloc] initWithMapView:MapView];
[mapView addOverlay: dimOverlay];
```

**Create and return MKOverlayView** for the specific MKOverlay **in 'viewForOverlay'** delegate method

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if([overlay isMemberOfClass:[MKMapDimOverlay class]]) {
        MKMapDimOverlayView *dimOverlayView = [[MKMapDimOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        return dimOverlayView;
    }
}
```

Since all you want is a colored overlay covering the map, your overlay and overlay view implementation will be very simple.

**DimOverlay.m**

```
@interface DimOverlay ()
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D dimOverlayCoordinates;
@end

@implementation DimOverlay

-(id)initWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView {
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.dimOverlayCoordinates = mapView.centerCoordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    return self.dimOverlayCoordinates;
}

-(MKMapRect)boundingMapRect {
    return MKMapRectWorld;
}

@end
```

**DimOverlayView.m**

```
@implementation DimOverlayView

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    /*
     You can allow custom colors and opacity values.
     Simply add UIColor and CGFloat properties in the overlay view class 
     and use those properties instead of the default hardcodes values below.
    */
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 0.85);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, [self rectForMapRect:mapRect]);
}

@end
```

Comment: If you don't need the map at all, you can choose to replace the whole map content by inserting this line in the top code snippet before you add it to the map `dimOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;`

Comment: How would I move the overlay when the user's location changes? Or change the color dynamically? Thanks!

Comment: @JacobR I also notice that this only paints some parts of the map. When moving, it leaves some parts "blank". How did you solve this?

Comment: @JacobR please check the [github project linked in the edited answer](https://github.com/lukya/MKMapDimOverlay).. it has custom color and shows the overlay over entire map irrespective of user's location or location changes.

Comment: @miya updated code in the answer now works for iOS 8.3